# ADODB.Stream in JavaScript - Skip lines beginnig with (Regex or for loop)

Tags: javascript, adodb

The program I'm writing for is a program called [Arsclip](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97/).

I have an external file I want to read like so that has lines beginning with `//` that I don't want to be included in the final returned `strData` variable.

```
// Enter your email subject below.
Enter Your Subject Here
```

The function I have to read the file and remove any lines that begin with `//`.

```js
// Usage:
fileOpReadFileContents(filepath)

function fileOpReadFileContents (file) {
var objStream, strData;
objStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8";
objStream.Open;
objStream.LoadFromFile(file);
strData = objStream.ReadText();
objStream.Close;
strData = strData.replace(/^\s*\/\/.*/gm, ''); // This is the line that removes the commentened out lines.
return strData;
}
```

This does the job fine.

**Q:** I was wondering if this method or using a for loop to read each line would be best practice?

I didn't and don't know how I could implement the later with JavaScript so I went with the regex replace method.

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest rewriting this code to move away from `ActiveXObject`. At this point "best practice" is no longer even in the same building as that code.

Comment: What are the alternatives so I can try them? I think I'm fairly limited to the `ActiveXObject` method as far as I can tell with the program I'm writing macros for.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention you're writing macros for a program. When you use the JavaScript tag, people are going to assume a browser host unless there are tags that say otherwise. JavaScript does have a File API in recent incarnations...

Comment: I don't have enough rep to add the programs name as a tag so I've added it to the Q.